# OCX registration with WiX

Tags: wix, registry, installation, ocx

I'm trying to add to my WiX setup a ocx registration. I do this:

```
heat.exe file MyFile.ocx -out C:\TEMP\registration.wxs
```

and it generates a .wxs that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
            <Directory Id="dirC202475C84215EEEECB6F7F457B64EC0" Name="data" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dirC202475C84215EEEECB6F7F457B64EC0">
            <Component Id="cmpEA6A1F59D6A38919A7ABA0CC22077BAD" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
                <File Id="filD9FC7A2F17B4650D687BA4E565868379" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\data\MyFile.ocx">
                  ...
```

I don't know how to say to the main wxs, say Product.wxs how to include this information to register the OCX during setup.
After running the setup I check in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID but I can't find the ocx's guid. 
I can find it if I run a regsvr32.exe e:\MyFile.ocx

**More info**

Cannot see any reference to the ocx guids in the installation log generated with msiexec

**Ugly solution**

I copied the heat-generated Fragments into my Module and it works. Still can't find out how to reference the same content on a separated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make components part of a build, you have to reference them as individual components or as a group. To make it easier to identify the component, heat has a "-cg" argument by with you can Id a ComponentGroup that references all the components. Just add a ComponentGroupRef with the applicable Id to one or more Feature elements.

(You also have to use the .wxs file in the build but I figure you've got that covered.)

Comment: and was my fault that I was using a Fragment in a msm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like heat is failing to harvest the COM meta data from the OCX file.  Usually this is a missing dependency.